# Выключить warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Как выключить варнинги в jupyter notebook? Их очень много. Они всё застилают

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше относиться, поначалу, к варнингам как к ошибкам и исправлять их, для легкого отлаживания кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
```

Либо

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```